# Handling custom LocalDateTime via XMLJavaTypeAdapter

Tags: xml, jaxb, java-time

I am using the XMLAdapter to parse the value in the request body to LocalDateTime.
Is there any way that I can create a custom exception for it, especially DateTimeParseException?

---

```
public class LocalDateTimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDateTime> {
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDateTime v) throws Exception {
        return v.format(formatter);
    }

    @Override
    public LocalDateTime unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return LocalDateTime.parse(v, formatter);
    }

}
```

---

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("ge")
@XmlElement(name = "ge")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime ge;

@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("le")
@XmlElement(name = "le")
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime le;
```

Comment: I tried creating a Controller Advice that catches the DateTimeParseException with high order precedence,  but it seems it is following the adapter way of catching exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To handle custom exception, i created my own LocalDateTime validator on top of the XMLAdapter. Validation is if the object is null it means DateTimeParseException occured during the XMLAdapter.

---

```
public class LocalDateTimeFormatValidator implements ConstraintValidator<LocalDateTimeFormat, Object> {

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        if (value != null) {
            return true;
        } else {
            throw new <YourException>(StringUtils.EMPTY, "Your Message");
        }
    }

}
```

---

```
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = LocalDateTimeFormatValidator.class)
public @interface LocalDateTimeFormat {
    String message() default "Invalid  Date format.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

---

```
@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("ge")
@LocalDateTimeFormat
@XmlElement(name = "ge", nillable = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime ge;

@JsonFormat(shape = Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("le")
@LocalDateTimeFormat
@XmlElement(name = "le", nillable = true)
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateTimeAdapter.class)
private LocalDateTime le;
```